# How to split string using regex in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Below is my string format.

```
test_string=`"test (11 MHz - 11 MHz)"`
 test1_string = 'test1 (11 MHz - 11 MHz)'
```

Needed output like below using regex in python:

```
output = ["test1", "11 MHz", "11 MHz"]
```

Comment: Give a [mcve] illustrating the specific problem with your attempt

Comment: @rts He probably meant, please show your current regex pattern / attempt for easier being able to help by seeing where it failed.

Comment: Why would you expect otherwise? You're just splitting on whitespace, you might as well write `"A1-A4 US (430 Mhz - 780 Mhz)".split()`.

Comment: For this try something like [`res = re.findall(r'(?im)^[^)(]+\b|\d+ mhz', str)`](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolYuruKRIwVZB3dFU19FCQcPU1EDB16NKQVfBzNgCxNJU5@IqSi0GKilK1UvLzEtJzMnRKFLXsM/M1YyLjtPUiNWOSaqJSdFWyM2oUtdRABqnyVVQlJlXogHUpvn/PwA)

Comment: @bobblebubble Working as i expected. thanks. If u post the answer then i will upvote.

Comment: @bobblebubble Make sure you avoid using `str` as a variable name in Python, it  is a builtin.

Comment: Using the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) you might also use `(?:^(\w+(?:-\w+)+(?: [A-Z]+)?) \(|\G(?!^))(\d+ MHz)(?: - (?!\)))?(?=[^()]*\))` https://regex101.com/r/rkYclW/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea with either *non parenthesis* at start or digits followed by `mhz` anywhere.

```
res = re.findall(r'(?i)^[^)(]+\b|\d+ mhz', test_string)
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pqYWqM/1) or a [Python demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolYurJLW4JL64pCgzL13BVkHd0VTX0ULB0clZQcPU1EDB16NKQVfBzNgCxNJU5@IqSi0GKitK1UvLzEtJzMnRKFLXsM/M1YyLjtPUiNWOSaqJSdFWyM2oUtdRQDJak6sASJVoALVr/v8PAA)

- with [flag](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) `(?i)` for *ignorecase* to match lower and upper `Mhz`
- `^[^)(]+\b` the first part will match *one or more* [non](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) parentheses from `^` start until a [`\b`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)
- `|` OR `\d+ mhz` *one or more* digits followed by the specified substring

This will work as long as your input matches the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This regex seems to do the job `([^(\n]*) \((\d* Mhz) - (\d* Mhz)\)`

[You can try it online](https://regex101.com/r/PpCyBH/1)

The website gives some code you can use for matcing with Python

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"([^(\n]*) \((\d* Mhz) - (\d* Mhz)\)"

test_str = ("A1-A4 US (430 Mhz - 780 Mhz)\n"
    "A7-A8 PS (420 Mhz - 180 Mhz)\n")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

Answer (score 0):

Using named groups:

```
import re
sample = "A1-A4 US (430 Mhz - 780 Mhz)"

split_pat = r"""
    (?P<first>.+)               # Capture everything up to first space
    \s\(                        # Skip space and initial parentheses
    (?P<second>\d+\s\bMhz\b)    # Capture numeric values, space, and Mhz
    \s+?\-\s+?                  # Skip hyphen in the middle
    (?P<third>\d+\s\bMhz\b)     # Capture numeric values, space, and Mhz
    \)                          # Check for closing  parentheses
    """

# Use re.X flag to handle verbose pattern string
p = re.compile(split_pat, re.X)

first_text = p.search(sample).group('first')
second_text = p.search(sample).group('second')
third_text = p.search(sample).group('third')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.findall` to search the text:

```
import re

text = "A1-A4 US (430 Mhz - 780 Mhz)"

first_text, second_text, third_text = re.findall(r'(.*?US).*?(\d+.Mhz).*?(\d+.Mhz)', text)[0]
print(first_text)
print(second_text)
print(third_text)
```

Prints:

```
A1-A4 US
430 Mhz
780 Mhz
```